# File Path Is Giving An Error (None of these files exist)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to import {auth} from firebase.js, and I have it set up as follows:

CareTeamScreen.js

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/core'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {KeyboardAvoidingView, Button, StyleSheet, Image, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {auth} from '.../firebase.js';
```

However, I get an error that the file does not exist.
None of these files exist:

```
  * ../../../.../firebase.js(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * ../../../.../firebase.js/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  3 | import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
  4 | import {KeyboardAvoidingView, Button, StyleSheet, Image, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList} from 'react-native';
> 5 | import {auth} from '.../firebase.js';
    |                     ^
  6 |
  7 | const CareTeamScreen = () => {
  8 |   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

I already tried './firebase.js', '../firebase.js', and '..../firebase.js'. They all did not work. I am also attaching how my file system is set up.

[image: file system]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to go up two directories it should be `../../` instead of `...`. I believe you are used to `...` due to zsh alias but it won't work with JS codebase